# safeAreaInsets return wrong values in viewDidLoad, where's the best place to get it?

Tags: ios, ios11, iphone-x

When I try to retrieve the safeAreaInsets in viewDidLoad in my view controller, it returns (0, 0, 0, 0) on the iPhone X, which I know is wrong. The documentation says that this will happen if the view is not part of the hierarchy or the view isn't visible. So my question is, where is the best place to retrieve the safeAreaInsets and then layout my subviews using these insets?

Comment: Are you using auto layout or doing layout manually in code?

Comment: @nathan I'm doing manual layout with frames in this case

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead of `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    // your layout code here
}
```

**Note:** Unlike `viewDidLoad` which is only called once, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is often called multiple times. Make sure to only set the frames inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, and don't perform operations that should only happen once, like adding subviews.

Comment: This is a good idea, but unfortunately in my case it's getting called during a rotation with incorrect safeAreaInsets, which is causing me problems. For most it likely won't matter, but just heads up to anyone else seeing this... it's sometimes called with strange insets (probably during animation).

Comment: @Oded but do you get `viewWillLayoutSubviews ` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` be called *multiple* times during rotation?

Comment: @nathan I think you can use `viewWillLayoutSubviews` instead of `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: @YevhenDubinin It's been a few weeks since I worked on that code but I think I did.

Comment: @Oded anyway, the solution proposed by @nathan here should work. You can take a look at my blog post: ["Abstract away from device model when adapting UI to iPhone X"](https://medium.com/@euginedubinin/abstract-away-from-device-model-when-adapting-ui-to-iphone-x-97df26e8e38), where `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is also used.